# Connection refused when running a script fragment in a Zeppelin notebook paragraph

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-zeppelin, aws-glue

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-notebook.html) to setup a local apache Zeppelin notebook to test AWS Glue ETL scripts.

I think I've done everything mentioned in [Tutorial Prerequisites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-prerequisites.html) and [Tutorial: Local Zeppelin Notebook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-notebook.html).

But when I run the following script in the notebook.

```
%pyspark
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.transforms import *

# Create a Glue context
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

# Create a DynamicFrame using the 'persons_json' table
persons_DyF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="legislators", table_name="persons_json")

# Print out information about this data
print "Count:  ", persons_DyF.count()
persons_DyF.printSchema()
```

I got an error saying

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:62)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:133)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:165)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:299)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:407)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here's my configuration of spark interpreter:

[image]

[image]

I use run zeppelin inside a docker container(`docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.8.0`).

I've also setup port forwarding using the command `ssh -i my_private_key.pem -vnNT -L :9007:169.254.76.1:9007 glue@ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.region.compute.amazonaws.com`.

Here's a complete log found in `/zeppelin/logs/zeppelin--XXXXXXXXXX.log`:

```
INFO [2018-10-18 03:40:29,438] ({qtp1458849419-14} VFSNotebookRepo.java[save]:196) - Saving note:2DS6DYE8N
 INFO [2018-10-18 03:40:29,471] ({pool-2-thread-2} SchedulerFactory.java[jobStarted]:109) - Job 20181018-033943_1834157789 started by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter-spark:existing_process-existing_process
 INFO [2018-10-18 03:40:29,473] ({pool-2-thread-2} Paragraph.java[jobRun]:380) - Run paragraph [paragraph_id: 20181018-033943_1834157789, interpreter: , note_id: 2DS6DYE8N, user: anonymous]
ERROR [2018-10-18 03:40:29,474] ({pool-2-thread-2} Job.java[run]:190) - Job failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:141)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:165)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:299)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:407)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:62)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:133)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
    ... 21 more
ERROR [2018-10-18 03:40:29,478] ({pool-2-thread-2} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2294) - Error
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:141)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:165)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:299)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:407)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:62)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:133)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
    ... 21 more
 WARN [2018-10-18 03:40:29,479] ({pool-2-thread-2} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2302) - Job 20181018-033943_1834157789 is finished, status: ERROR, exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), result: %text java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:62)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:133)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:165)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:299)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:407)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

 INFO [2018-10-18 03:40:29,489] ({pool-2-thread-2} VFSNotebookRepo.java[save]:196) - Saving note:2DS6DYE8N
 INFO [2018-10-18 03:40:29,494] ({pool-2-thread-2} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:115) - Job 20181018-033943_1834157789 finished by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter-spark:existing_process-existing_process
```

How can I debug this issue now?

I don't find many discussions about this bug online.

Comment: When you put the setting `localhost` into the interpreter page, that would be the localhost of the running docker container. The ssh tunnel is running on your host machine. How to reconcile that?

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue when running Zeppelin 0.8.0, but switching to Zeppelin 0.7.3 seemed to resolve it.